# Why the NO Null constrained error keeps raising when trying to comment

Tags: django-models, django-views

I am trying to comment in a room but anytime I commented a Non NUll constrained error raised and I cannot find the problem.

The models are as follows:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

The views is as follows:

```
def room(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_messages = room.message_set.all().order_by('-created')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            room=room,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        return redirect('room', pk=room.id)
    context = {
        'room': room, 'room_messages':room_messages
    }
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

The html:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="comment-form">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- {{form}} -->
        <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Write your message here..."/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock content %}

Comment: Likely because `request.POST` does not contain a value for the `body` key. Can you share the HTML form?

Comment: I have included the html, please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found out that in the html I've assigned "comment" instead of "body" to the name=''" in the input tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).